# Changing row height with JTable.setRowHeight not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I'm working on a table that have rows suiting the contents. I install a TableModelListener to the table model so that whenever a new row is added, the height of the new added row is automatically changed. Here's my testing code:

```
final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
final JTable table = new JTable(model);
model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        // TO DO: replace 100 with the actual preferred height.
        table.setRowHeight(e.getFirstRow(), 100);
    }
});

JButton button = new JButton("Add Row");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.addRow(new String[] {"abc"});
    }
});
```

I expect that when "Add Row" button is clicked, a new row is added to the table and has a height of 100 pixels, but it doesn't work - the row height never changes. A weirder thing is that the `JTable.setRowHeight` method can work correctly if I move the call to the button's action listener like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.addRow(new String[] {"abc"});
        talbe.setRowHeight(table.getRowCount() - 1, 100);
    }
});
```

Definitely I can't rely on this "solution" because the table model can be changed from other places. Do I correctly use `TableModelListener` or is this a bug?

Comment: no bug - just keep in mind that the table is listening to its model as well and updates itself accordingly. That internal update must be complete before client code can act (that's what invokeLater is for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about to use EventQueue.invokeLater(...)

```
model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
  @Override public void tableChanged(final TableModelEvent e) {
    // TO DO: replace 100 with the actual preferred height.
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        table.setRowHeight(e.getFirstRow(), 100);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I still don't why `EventQueue.invokeLater` should be used here, because the `tableChanged` method is already running on the EDT. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you'll find that placing the call outside the event listener (via invoke later) is causing the repaint manager to update the component - hence the suggestion to try invalidate; but you have a working solution

Comment: Sorry, some of requests to the repaint manager with in the event listener may be getting absorbed

Comment: @ZhaoYi read the api doc of invokeLater to find out what (besided guaranteeing to execute the runnable on the EDT) the method promises :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to invalidate/repaint the table after setting the row height value?

Comment: The `JTable.setRowHeight` method will invoke `revalidate` and `repaint`, so this should not be the problem.